# Is there an online list of English sefarim?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, english

Funky question. Hopefully this will help clarify.

Example:

I am (was) currently looking for a set of the Mishnah Berurah that has been translated into English. I just found this today:

http://zbermanbooks.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=MISHNAH+BERURAH.

Excuse my ugly link. I just happened to stumble upon zberman while looking at another question (Yay M.Y.!) and decided to explore a little. Very happy about this find.

Now, though I don't mind getting tangled up in the big 'www' until 2am, I would still greatly appreciate a resource that stays up-to date on publishers - big or small - that produce bi-lingual (i.e. English/Hebrew) products or full translations. The idea of a blog came to mind, if anyone is aware of such a miracle. : ) There are a lot of projects like Ohr Olam's Mishnah Berurah  or Yalkut Yosef popping up across the globe producing material for English speakers. It would be cool to have a 'go-to' place for info on current and coming works.

Yes, I know this is a bit too convenient. And no, I don't want to rely on English forever. But as it's been said: The answer is always no until you ask.

The other thing I've ran into now a few times, are links to articles, books, etc. in English that are no longer active/connected though the site is still up and running. If that made any sense.

Thank you for sourcing/linking!

Comment: What qualifies as a "Sefer" that an English translation of it would be notable?

Comment: As you know, Art Scroll is one of the main publishers of English "sefarim" (Gee, DoubleAA is right on his question!) So, that may be a good start and perhaps cover most of what you may need (pending your question edits.) Feldheim publishers is another big one. Does Hebrew Publishing CO. still exist?

Comment: @DoubleAA Was waiting for this question. :) And if I understand it correctly: 1) I'll say 'core' areas of study i.e. Halacha (Ben Ish Chai), Ethics/Mussar (Mesillat Yesharim), etc. 2) Teshuvot, Responsum 3) Commentaries. To be honest, I'm thinking ' I really don't know'.

Comment: @DanF http://www.hebrewpublishing.com/

Comment: It sounds like what you are seeking is a consolidated list of links. If that's it, what happens if you do a Google search using something like "Publishers of Hebrew books translated to English"? I'd think that should give you something and it should be as good as or better than what we would answer, here.

Comment: Just thinking of another strategy, which is what I occasionally use. When I stop in a local *Bet Midrash* or shul library, to learn, I sometimes see a list of translated books. I browse the shelves and if I find something I like, I consider buying it. Or, as you've figured out, browse book / Judaica stores. Try Eichler's. They're pretty large.

Comment: Re'eh, I don't think that that's the same Hebrew Publishing Co. that @DanF is referring to. My great-uncle ש”י used to work for them doing typography and only left when the company closed after attempts to unionise failed (back in the 1980s IIRC).

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt I haven't seen the link. But, from what I recall, HPC published only all Hebrew books. Well OK, some of the instructions in their Siddurim wre in English and / or Yiddish or Hebrew.

Comment: @DanF, the Birnbaum siddur and machzor were HPC, as were the Stern, Phillips, et al. siddurim with translation. They also had translations of Chumash and Tana"ch and a partial translation of M"T, IIRC.

Comment: http://jkuperman.com/TorahLinks/OnlineTexts.html

This might help